# A subset that forms a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> Consider the complex vector space $\mathbb{C^3}$ and the subset $$S = {(1,0,i),\ (i, 2, −3),\ \ (2 − i, 1 + i, i)}$$
> Let V denote the span of S.
>
> (a)Find a subset of S that forms a basis for V.
>
> (b) What is the dimension of V ?

I am trying to solve this but I am not sure how to do it fully.

This is what I have thus far:

Reducing V = $\begin{bmatrix}1&i&2-i \\ 0&2&1+i \\ i&-3&i  \end{bmatrix}$ to R.E.F:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}1&i&2-i \\ 0&2&1+i \\ i&-3&i  \end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix} i&-3&i \\ 0&-2i&1-i \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} $$

I know I have to somehow get the basis from this row echelon matrix but I am not sure how to proceed, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The reduced echelon form indicates that the set of vectors in $S$ are linearly dependent. Another observation is that there is no pair of vectors in $S$ such that one of them is a complex scalar multiple of another. This means any pair of vectors in $S$ is a linearly independent set and thus, forms a basis for span(S).

dimension of V is simply the number of vectors in the basis.

Comment: so either ${(i,0,0},  (-3,-2i,0)}$ or any of the other two pairs? and the dimension of V would be 2?

Comment: No. I mean any pair in the original set S.

Comment: okay thank you! and the dimension is still 2?